# Error: no se ha encontrado el método principal en la clase Prueba

Tags: java

Un tablero de dardos está compuesto por Cinco aros concéntricos como se muestra en la figura. La tabla siguiente muestra el radio de cada uno de estos aros y el puntaje otorgado por un dardo en cada uno de los colores. Suponga que el centro del tablero es el punto (0, 0). Calcule el puntaje obtenido con un dardo que golpea el tablero en el punto (x, y). Color Rojo Naranja Amarillo Verde Azul Puntaje 15 9 5 2 1 Radio 1 2 3 4 5
Llevo esto:

```
static double dardos (int x, int y) { 
double dist = Math.sqrt((x-0)*(x-0)+(y-0)*(y-0)); 
if (dist < 1){ 
    return System.out.println(“15 puntos”); 
} else { 
    if (1 < dist && dist <= 2) { 
        return System.out.println(“9 puntos”); 
} else { 
    if (2 < dist && dist <= 3) { 
         return System.out.println(“5 puntos”); 
} else { 
    if (3 < dist && dist <= 4) { 
        return System.out.println(“2 puntos”); 
} else { 
    if(4 < dist && dist <=5) { 
        return System.out.println(“1 punto”); 
} else { 
    return System.out.println(“0 puntos, cayó fuera del tablero.”); 
}
```

Tengo este error:

> Error: no se ha encontrado el método principal en la clase Prueba, defina el método principal del siguiente modo:\n public static void main(String[] args)\nde lo contrario, se deberá ampliar una clase de aplicación JavaFX javafx.application.Application

Me pueden ayudar, gracias.

Comment: static double dardos (int x, int y){

    double dist = Math.sqrt((x-0)*(x-0)+(y-0)*(y-0));

    if (dist < 1){
       return System.out.println(“15 puntos”);
}else{
   if (1 < dist && dist <= 2) {
   return System.out.println(“9 puntos”); 
}else{
   if (2 < dist && dist <= 3){
  return System.out.println(“5 puntos”);
}else{
  if (3 < dist && dist <= 4){
  return System.out.println(“2 puntos”);
}else{
  if(4 < dist && dist <=5){
  return System.out.println(“1 punto”);
}else{
  return System.out.println(“0 puntos, cayó fuera del tablero.”);

}

Comment: Eso es lo que llevo pero el return no me lo toma

Comment: Listo gracias y que pena

Comment: Error: no se ha encontrado el método principal en la clase Prueba, defina el método principal del siguiente modo:\n   public static void main(String[] args)\nde lo contrario, se deberá ampliar una clase de aplicación JavaFX javafx.application.Application

Comment: Me sale ese error

Comment: Te falta el método principal `public static void main(String[] args)` en tu código.

Comment: Ya se lo agregue pero aun me aparece error

Comment: el error en tu codigo es que tu funcion debe retornar un double pero estas poniendo 
return System.out.println(“.........
y lo que debes poner es return dist;
para que devuelva la distancia abajo puse una respuesta con el metodo correctamente.

Answer (score 2):

Éste sería el método usando geometria analítica para calcular [la distancia al punto](https://sites.google.com/site/geometriaanalitica3o/distancia-entre-dos-puntos):

```
    double calcularDistancia(int x, int y){
            int xOrigen=0;
            int yOrigen=0;
    
            double distancia=Math.sqrt(
                    Math.pow((x-xOrigen),2)
                            +
                            Math.pow((y-yOrigen),2)
            );
    
            if(distancia<=1)
                System.out.print("puntaje 15");
            if(distancia<=2 && distancia>1)
                System.out.print("puntaje 9");
            if(distancia<=3 && distancia>2)
                System.out.print("puntaje 5");
            if(distancia<=4&& distancia>3)
                System.out.print("puntaje 2");
            if(distancia<=5&& distancia>4)
                System.out.print("puntaje 1");
            if(distancia>5)
                System.out.print("afuera");

return distancia;
        }
```

Con respecto a este error:

> Error: no se ha encontrado el método principal en la clase Prueba, defina el método principal del siguiente modo:\n public static void main(String[] args)\nde lo contrario, se deberá ampliar una clase de aplicación JavaFX javafx.application.Application

Debes crear el método `main` en esa misma clase:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    NOMBRRE_DE_TU_CLASE ndtc=new NOMBRRE_DE_TU_CLASE();
    ndtc.dardos(0, 1);
}
```

Comment: Con el comentario de la pregunta se complementaría mejor la respuesta.